# Google Conversion Not showing image

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to incorporate the **google conversion tracking** feature in my webpage but the little image that is supposed to show is not showing. Now google stresses to put the code within the body tags--

```
<html>
  <body>    
   <!-- Google Code for Purchase Conversion Page -->
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   <!--
    var google_conversion_id = 1234567890;
    var google_conversion_language = "en_US";
    var google_conversion_format = "1";
    var google_conversion_color = "666666";
    if (1.0) {
        var google_conversion_value = 1.0;
      }
    var google_conversion_label = "Purchase"; //-->
   </script>
   <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
   </script>
 <noscript>
     <img height=1 width=1 border=0   src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1234567890/?    value=5.0&label=Purchase&script=0">
  </noscript>
 </body>
 <html>
```

Thank you

Comment: By the way, that doesn't look like google ads code, what is that?  Can you provide a link to where Google says to do that with your code?

Comment: Well its actually the Purchase conversion actually, I need to change the title i was confused

Comment: please clarify your question, I'm confused as to what your actual problem is.

Comment: Do you mean the img in the noscript, or the image usually loaded by the Google script? You can remove the `language` and `type` attributes for scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the posted code, the img tag only gets rendered or "shows" if javascript is disabled.  If javascript is enabled, the javascript in the conversion.js generates an iframe with the src url being similar to what you see in that noscript img src url, except for more detailed.

And as for when it "shows"... it's a 1x1 transparent pixel, so I hope you aren't trying to eyeball on your screen...